# OpenGL fast rendering 2d image

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

My current drawing pipeline is like most of the existing examples on the internet but when rendering several videos at the same time, this rendering 2D texture pipeline can be very slow. Are there ways to improve that ? Can anyone provide some examples? Thanks.

```
// when initializing
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, image.cols,
         image.rows, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
         NULL);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glFinish();


// another thread to load image
cv::Mat image = loadImage();

//initializeGL()
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

//paintGL()
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glLoadIdentity();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, image.cols,
             image.rows,  GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             image.data);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(width, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(width, height,  0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(0,  height,  0.0f);
glEnd();
```

Comment: So are you rendering several videos from your app?

Comment: @Asesh yes. Actually, it is several received video frames.

Comment: I see you are using OpenCV too. Looks like cv::Mat image = loadImage(); is the bottleneck

Comment: @Asesh the loading function is in another thread, this is just for completeness purpose. The loadImage is not the bottleneck.

Comment: Are those codes from the same method? If this method gets executed every frame then I see no reason to call glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity(); every frame. You can just call them once when initializing OpenGL

Comment: @Asesh  sorry for the misunderstanding. I modified it a bit.

Comment: To be frank, your code looks fine. Just because cv::Mat image = loadImage(); runs in a separate thread doesn't mean it can't be a bottle neck. What synchronization mechanism are you using to read data from 'image'? You can use NVIDIA nSight, if you have NVIDIA graphics card to profile your app. If I were you I would spend some time trying to find the bottleneck by profiling it